# Was ist das für ein Wortspiel?

Tags: terminology

Was ist der Fachbegriff für das Wortspiel, das in

> Q: Was ist aller Laster Anfang?
>   A: Die Stoßstange

verwendet wurde?

Comment: ein blödes Wortspiel?

Comment: @swegi: Mir ist kei besseres Beispiel eingefallen. Ich meine generell Wortspiele, bei denen ein Wort mit mehreren Bedeutungen gezielt misbraucht wird.

Comment: ein Kontextwechsel ;-)

Comment: Anderes Beispiel: Q: Was darf ich mir unter einer Spannbandbrücke vorstellen? A: Wasser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Für mich sieht das nach einer Art [Paraprosdokian](http://www.rhetorik.ch/Figuren/Figuren.html#32) aus. Die englischsprachige Wikipedia hat einen [entsprechenden Artikel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraprosdokian) mit vielen Beispielen. Die deutschsprachige leider nicht.

Comment: Trifft es auf den Punkt.

Answer (score 3):

[Polysemie](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemie) ist eine Mehrdeutigkeit von Wörtern, zumeist mit Homonymen (gleichlautende Wörter mit unterschiedlicher Bedeutung)

[Paronomasie](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paronomasie) geht in die gleiche Richtung, bezieht aber auch Wörter, die nur ähnlich klingen, mit ein.

Answer (score 2):

Ein verwandter deutschsprachiger Wikipediaartikel zu [Zeugma (ein Wort wird brutal in zwei verschiedenen Bedeutungen verwendet](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_%28Sprache%29)

Der Artikel enthält mehrere Beispiele, etwa:

„Ich heiße nicht nur Heinz Erhardt, sondern Sie auch herzlich willkommen.“

Answer (score 1):

Ich möchte noch kurz auf das Spiel [Teekesselchen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teekesselchen) hinweisen, bei dem es darum geht, genau solche Wörter so zu beschreiben, dass durch alle Bedeutungen das Wort erraten werden kann.